# LaPlace transform of $t^2\sin(at)$

Tags: laplace-transform

$$\int^{\infty}_{0} e^{-st}t^2\sin(at)dt$$

I keep running into a problem when using:

$$u=e^{-st}t^2$$ $$du=2te^{-st}-st^2e^{-st}$$

$$v=\frac{1}{a} \cos(at)$$

$$dv=\sin(at)$$

Anyone have any suggestions for how to proceed?  I've seen a slick substitution using Euler's formula but I'm not sure that it is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on what @ncmathsadist means is
$$
\int_0^{\infty}t^2e^{-st}\sin(at)dt 
$$ 
can be solved by using a more well known transform. Consider
$$
\mathcal{L}\{\sin(at)\} = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\sin(at)dt = \frac{a}{s^2 + a^2}
$$
Then 
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\mathcal{L}\{\sin(at)\} = \text{what integral?} = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\frac{a}{s^2 + a^2}
$$

Comment: dustin - I've watched a few videos on using Leibniz rule and, though I now understand that rule perfectly, am still having trouble solving this. I integrated under the integral twice and then tried solving by parts from there and taking the limit. I'm not sure how to use the sub you suggest here.  This is the first LaPlace transform i've ever attempted.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-st}\sin(at)dt = \int_0^{\infty}t^2e^{-st}\sin(at)dt = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$$

Comment: Oh...man I just realized what you meant. Now I feel ridiculous.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try invoking the Leibnitz rule and differentiating twice under the integral sign with respect to $s$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rule. Could you give a bit of detail?

Comment: If $F(y) = \int_a^b f(x, y)\, dx$ then $F'(y) = \int_a^b (\partial/\partial s)f(x,y)\, dx$ if the integrand is reasonably well-behaved.